# Keep inner div from sliding left after adding to table

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP page that adds and removes values to the table in a div element contained by a div wrapper. The goal is to have the table build to the right and remain fixed at the left most position (code below). The code I have centers everything initially, but the table shifts as values get added or removed. See the pictures below for a clearer picture of what I am talking about.

Before scrolling: My question: How do I keep the left edge of the inner div fixed while it grows right?

Centered div inside a wrapper div, looks good!.

[image]

After a new user is inputted, it shifts left, instead I want the div to grow right. As you can see the edge of the div on the left is no longer under the N of demonstrate, instead it is at the t in to. Confused as to why this is. See CSS below.
[image]

CSS for this example:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;

    /* this is what centers your element in the fixed wrapper*/
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center; /* aligns on vertical for column */
    align-items: center; /* aligns on horizontal for column */

    /* just for styling to see the limits */
    border: 2px dashed red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px dashed purple;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Creating these tables(reading from ini file and dynamically making tables with each section):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="element">
    <?php 
        $file = "pages/test.ini";
        $data = parse_ini_file($file, true);

        foreach ($data as $section => $section_content) {
    ?>
            <table style='padding:5px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;'>
                <h3><?=$section?>   <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' id='<?=$section?>' onclick="add(id, 'addUser')" style='padding: 2px;'></i><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' id='<?=$section?>' onclick="remove(id, 'removeUser')" style='padding: 2px;'></i></h3>
                    <td style='padding:2px; border: 1px solid black;'><strong>Users</strong></td>
                    <td style='padding:2px; border: 1px solid black;'><?=$section_content['users'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='padding:2px; border: 1px solid black;'><strong>Groups</strong></td>
                    <td style='padding:2px; border: 1px solid black;'><?=$section_content['groups'];?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    

        <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try enabling a scroll `overflow-x:auto` or breaking the word on multiple lines `word-break: break-all;` which depends on your layout and your desired end result

Comment: I notice .element is absolute; try adding `left: 200px` and see if that makes it stick. Do you want it to be absolutely positioned? You could instead add margin to the parent container and then make the flex items align `left`.

Comment: @willoller the left:200px in the element tag seemed to make it stick. I do want it to be absolutely positioned also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason this is happening is the purple `.element` container is positioned using `flex` and does not have a set `height` or `width`. So, it grows with the content.

You could resolve this in many ways, depending on what your needs are.

1. Set a `width` or `max-width` on `.element`
2. Set .container to flex align left and give `.container` some `margin-left` to give the left position
3. Add a `left` position to `.container` so it will only grow to the right